# How do you debug a MongoDB query?

Tags: debugging, mongodb

I have a MongoDB query that I'm running, and its not pulling back a record that I know it should. I filter on two things: category and description (via a contains/like regular expression). If I search based on category, all of the records in that category comes back (including the problem record), but if I throw in description, I cannot get that record to come back. Other records that match the description text come back, but for some reason, no matter what I put in, I can't get this one record to come back with a description condition. It's very bizarre.

How does one go about debugging such a thing with MongoDB? My query is very simple:

```
var match = {};

var category = "hardware"
if (category)
    match.Category = category;

var searchText = "ceramic"
if (searchText)
{
    match.Description = new RegExp("/.*" + searchText + ".*/");
}

collection.find(match).toArray(function(err, items)
{
    response.send(items);
});
```

The item that I'm trying to get back is in the hardware category and it comes back when searchText is "". It has the word "ceramic" in its description, but when searchText is "ceramic" (or any number of other words found in its description), that item just won't come back. Others with the word "ceramic" in their description do, but not that one, and of course the structure of that item is no different from the other items. It really should be passing the match.

The casing is correct ("ceramic" is all lowers in both the description and the filter), and I've also tried /i to make the search case-insensitive.

So how can I find out why this query is failing to produce an item that very clearly matches it?

Comment: There's got to be something different about that doc that won't come back in the "ceramic" query.  Can you add that doc to the post?

Answer (score 2):

Well, this probably is not the cause here, but that regex is a bit odd.  You should just be able to specify this:

match.Description = new RegExp("/" + searchText + "/");

The `.*` means match any character any number of times - unless you are trying to match everything up to the text greedily and use it as part of a more complex regex then you don't need it.

In terms of debugging, figure out what your query should look like in MongoDB and make sure it works in the shell.  Here's a quick sample doc:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("503fab7bf6a278b7bda257d2"),
    "category" : "hardware",
    "Description" : "blah ceramic blah"
}
```

And this matches:

```
mongos> db.foo.find({"Description" : /ceramic/}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("503fab7bf6a278b7bda257d2"),
    "category" : "hardware",
    "Description" : "blah ceramic blah"
}
```

You can also [turn on profiling](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler#DatabaseProfiler-EnablingProfiling) and watch to see what your program is sending to MongoDB (be careful, profiling has overheads).  You will want level 2 to be able to see all queries as mentioned on the page.